# Binary bitwise X-OR operation returning unexpected answer for multiple X-OR operations at once

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, xor

I expect that `13<op>31<op>131` equals `(13<op>31) <op> (31<op>131)` for binary bitwise operations. This is working for bitwise AND operations, but not for bitwise X-OR operations.

In Bitwise AND operations, I'm getting the answer as expected:

```py
>>> 13&31&131
1
>>> 13&31
13
>>> 31&131
3
>>> 13&3
1
```

But in Bitwise X-OR operation, I'm not getting it as expected:

```py
>>> 13^31^131
145
>>> 13^31
18
>>> 31^131
156
>>> 18^156
142    <<--- I expect this to be 145
```

I can't figure it where I'm missing the concept. Can anyone kindly help me out?

Comment: Maybe easier to understand with `1 ^ 1 ^ 1`

Comment: Why would you expect that?

Comment: @HeapOverflow because of the first example.

Answer (score 1):

The last expression that you expect to be 145 should be `18 ^ 131`...which is 145. It should not have 156 as the second operator because that means you are doing the operation on the 31 in the middle twice.

Comment: Oh, I see! That means it should be: `13^31^131` equals `((13^31)^131)`. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

```
(13 xor 31) xor (31 xor 131)
```

Does not equal

```
13 xor 31 xor 131
```

Instead, it's the same as

```
13 xor 131
```

Your expectation works if `a op a == a`, which is true for `and` and `or`, but not for `xor`, `nor` or `nand`.

Comment: Then how is `13^31^131` ending up being `145`?

Comment: Are you asking to explain what the xor operator does?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a simple calculator https://xor.pw/# and do Xor, it returns 142. Do not forget xor means :

A | B | R = A Xor B 
0 | 0  |  0 
0 | 1  |  1 
1 | 0  |  1 
1 | 1  |  0